# In C, why is dereferenced array pointer identical to the pointer itself?

Tags: arrays, c, dereference

In the code below, I declare an int array "a" and then a pointer to the entire array "ap":

```
int main(){
        int a[3] = {10, 100, 1000};
        int (*ap)[] = &a;

        printf("%p\n", ap);
        printf("%p\n", *ap);
        printf("%d\n", **ap);

        return 0;
}
```

The first print of ap shows that it is actually a pointer to the first value of the array. OK.
But in the second print, ap is dereferenced and, yet, the value is the same: pointer to the first value of the array.
It's only after a "double dereferencing" that I get the value of the first array element (10 in my example):

```
0x7fff193310cc
0x7fff193310cc
10
```

Why is that so?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The address of an array and the address of the first element of the array point to the same place, so the have _equivalent_ addresses: `&a == a`.  Yet their printed values _may_ differ as pointers are not specified to use a linear model.  Even their sizes may differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `*ap` it's basically the same as doing `*(&a)`, which is in essence plain `a`.

And as arrays decays to pointers to their first elements, plain `a` is the same as `&a[0]`.

Now here's the interesting thing: The location of the array `a` and the location of the first element of `a` is the exact same location.

It's easy to see if we draw it out:

```
+------+------+------+
| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] |
+------+------+------+
^
|
&a[0]
|
&a
```

See how both `&a[0]` and `&a` are pointing to the same location?

But also remember that while both `&a[0]` and `&a` are pointing to the same location, they have very different types:

- `&a[0]` will have the type `int *`
- `&a` will have the type `int (*)[3]`

Comment: Different types, right until the point they are passed as function argument, at which point `int (*)[3]` degenerates into `int *`.

Comment: Array decaying to pointer is what most people find confusing.

Answer (score 2):

`ap` is a pointer to an array. In the program execution you observed, the array starts at address 7FFF193310CC<sub>16</sub>.

Since `ap` is a pointer to an array, `*ap` is an array. When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of unary `&`, the operand of `sizeof`, or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Therefore, `*ap` is converted to a pointer to `(*ap)[0]`. Naturally, the first element of an array starts in the same place the array does, since it is the first thing in the array, so its address is 7FFF193310CC<sub>16</sub>.

Since `*ap` is automatically converted to a pointer to `(*ap)[0]`, `**ap` is the thing it points to, which is `(*ap)[0]`, so it is the first element of the array, not a pointer.

Note that, to have behavior defined by the C standard when printing a pointer, you should convert it to `void *`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) ap);
printf("%p\n", (void *) *ap);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+------+---------+----------+
|  10  |   100   |    1000  |  
+------+---------+----------+
^  ^ ^  
|  | |
|  | +------+
|  +---+    +--+
&ap    |       |
       *ap     **ap
```

- `&ap` points to the base address of the array, its type is `int (*)[3]` (pointer to array with 3 `int` elements).
- `*ap` points to the first element of the array, its type is `int *` (pointer to `int`).
- `**ap` yields the value stored at the address of the first element, its type is `int`.

---

> But in the second print, ap is dereferenced and, yet, the value is the same: pointer to the first value of the array.

The name of an array in C usually yields the address of the first element of the array.

However when you use the `&` operator in an expression such as `&arrayname`, it yields a pointer of type `T(*)[size]` instead of "pointer to the first element".

This means `&a` and `a` both have the same value, but they have completely different types, hence why `ap` and `*ap` also have the same value but different types.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a pointer to an object of the type int[3].

```
    int (*ap)[] = &a;
```

So the call of printf prints the address of the object of the type int[3]

```
    printf("%p\n", ap);
```

Dereferencing the pointer you get an array of an unknown size due to this declaration of the pointer `int (*ap)[]`. Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements. So the address of the first element of the array is outputted in this call of printf

```
printf("%p\n", *ap);
```

The addresses of the array itself and of its first element are equal each other.